# Cannot acquire Data Source in EclipseLink

Tags: tomcat, jpa, eclipselink, datasource, jndi

I have a Web Application (Netbeans + Maven) in Java EE backed with a local installation of Tomcat 8, My application runs Jersey for a web service. I'm trying to add EclipseLink for persistence (the database I'm accessing is a remote OracleDB), but I can't configure it right and I'm always greeted by a lot of exceptions every time I'm trying to create entities.

This is my code:

```
EntityManagerFactory factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(PERSISTENCE_UNIT_NAME);
EntityManager entityManager = factory.createEntityManager();
entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
```

it throws

> Exception [EclipseLink-7060] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException
>   Exception Description: Cannot acquire data source [jdbc/oracle].
>   Internal Exception: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [jdbc/oracle] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [jdbc].

I've been spending the better part of the day configuring web.xml, context.xml and persistence.xml and nothing works

EDIT:
When I add

```
<properties>
  <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@11.22.333.444:5555:XE"/>
  <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="xxxx"/>
  <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="xxxx"/>-->
  <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"/>

  <property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="WARNING"/>
  <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="create"/>
</properties>
```

to the persistence.xml, I get the following

> javax.persistence.PersistenceException: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Not supported by BasicDataSource
>       org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.deploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:762)
>       org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.getAbstractSession(EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.java:204)
>       org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.getDatabaseSession(EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.java:182)
>       org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.getDatabaseSession(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:527)
>       org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactoryImpl(PersistenceProvider.java:140)
>       org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceProvider.java:177)
>       javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:79)
>       javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:54)

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: try with `java:comp/env/jdbc/oracle` instead of just `jdbc/oracle`

Comment: where exactly ? I already have this in my persistence.xml : <persistence-unit name="projectname" transaction-type="JTA">
    <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
    <jta-data-source>java:comp/env/jdbc/oracle</jta-data-source>

Comment: Include your perstence.xml, context.xml, server.xml otherwise we cannot tell what is wrong. The properties you mentioned in your persitance.xml do not matter if you are using container's datasource.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/ks9bQtpf

Comment: How are you specifying JTA transactions in your application?  You should not be using JTA if you are specifying javax.persistence.jdbc properties in your persistence.xml, instead using resource_local and controlling the transactions yourself (entityManager.getTransaction().begin() etc).  See http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/Tomcat_Web_Tutorial though for an example of how to setup using JTA in Tomcat.